# Outlook Determine Users default mail font style and size

Tags: html, vba, outlook

Good morning - I am trying to draft an email programmatically from Access to Outlook.

I believe I have properly figured how to create the email, but cannot understand how to use the users default mail message font as the font type.  All messages are coming up Times New Roman, pt 12.

I've found plenty of articles on how to set the font to a certain style, but I want to use the users' default Outlook font settings.

```
Sub testHTML()
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient

          ' Create the Outlook session.
          Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

          ' Create the message.
          Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

          With objOutlookMsg
              ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
'              Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("Whatever Email")
'              objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo

             .Subject = "Testing"
             .Display

             'Create HTML body, which will contain a hyperlink
                objOutlookMsg.HTMLBody = "This is the body of the email, which contains a link to Google.  " & _
                                        "<a href='http://www.google.com'>www.google.com<a/>. " & _
                                        "Can you please help me figure out the font for the whole message?  " & _
                                        "Why does it default to Times New Roman point 12 instead of the users' default mail font?"
        End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the below:

```
objOutlookMsg= "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri>This is the body of the email, which contains a link to Google.  " & _
                                    "<a href='http://www.google.com'>www.google.com<a/>. " & _
                                    "Can you please help me figure out the font for the whole message?  " & _
                                    "Why does it default to Times New Roman point 12 instead of the users' default mail font?"</BODY>"
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - I could use your recommendation if I wanted to set it to Calibri size 11.  However, I do not wish to hard code the font - I prefer to simply let it default to the users settings for their outlook messages.  Do you have an alternative recommendation?

Comment: You can use the default font which you want, as the HTML have only 3 fonts and will select whichever is present.

Answer (score 0):

Hi There I check your problem. Outlook does not support the external font. So Times New Roman is the default font for outlook. You can use system default font like. arial. Plus you should define your font inline. That is the best way to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

The settings are stored in 
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\MailSettings` (where "`16.0`" is the Outlook version). the name of the font is embedded is in the `ComposeFontSimple` binary value; `ComposeFontComplex` seems to contain the HTML template used for new messages.